# compilation of netcdf-c-4.9.1 issue

Tags: hdf5, netcdf

I tried building netcdf-c-4.9.1 by first running `./configure` and then running `make`. Unfortunately, when running `make`, I encountered the following errors:

```
 ../liblib/.libs/libnetcdf.so: undefined reference to `H5free_memory'
 ../liblib/.libs/libnetcdf.so: undefined reference to `H5allocate_memory'
```

How do I resolve the undefined references?

Comment: If those are the only undefined reference errors, then the issue is probably that netcdf depends on a newer (or maybe older) version of HDF5 than you have installed (if you didn't have HDF5 at all then I would expect `configure` to have failed, and if it didn't, I would also expect more errors like those).  Check the NetCDF docs for version dependencies, and install a satisfactory version.

Comment: It's also possible that the HDF5 library simply wasn't linked. Maybe it is installed but not detected by `pkg-config`. If that is the case, then you might have to adjust `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` or pass flags to the linker manually.